# How to group functions in to a sprite and randomly position it

Tags: python, random, cpu-word, pygame, sprite

I recently came across something called PyGame Sprite's and would like to learn to create Pygame sprites as it will be very useful for my project.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)

objs = []

MAIN_BUTTON = 1

class Pane(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 25)
        pygame.display.set_caption('Box Test')
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400), 0, 32)
        self.screen.fill((white))
        pygame.display.update()

    def addRect(self):
        self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (black), (175, 75, 200, 100), 2)
        pygame.display.update()

    def addText(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.font.render('Hello', True, (black)), (250, 115))
        pygame.display.update()

    def delText(self):
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600,400), 0, 32)
        self.screen.fill((white))
        pygame.display.update()

    def mousePosition(self): #Ignore this.
        global clickPos
        global releasePos
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == MAIN_BUTTON:
                self.Pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                return MAIN_BUTTON
            else:
                return False
    def groupSp(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, group)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Pan3 = Pane()
    Pan3.addRect()
    Pan3.addText()
    Pan3.mousePosition()
    group = pygame.sprite.Group(Pan3.addRect(), Pan3.addText())
    Pan3.groupSp()
    group.sprites()
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                 pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
```

So I was wondering if you could group both addRect(self) and addText(self) as Sprite? If so is there a way of then being able to place it randomly on a screen? Or is there a better way of doing this?

In advance Thank-You for your time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to call `pygame.display.update()` once per game loop.  ( Right now, if you create two panes, and call addText() twice on each, that's 4 updates per loop. )

> if you could group both addRect(self) and addText(self) as Sprite?

You can render them to the same surface, which later is drawn on screen.

> If so is there a way of then being able to place it randomly on a screen?

To place randomly, use `random.randint()` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10667252/341744

> pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, group)

This should be called in your constructor `Pane.__init__`